# C# MVC Download dynamic File Name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How can I download a pdf file that's not static.

I tried this:

```
public ActionResult GetPdf(string filename)
{
   var invoice = db.Invoices.ToList().Find(x=>x.InvoicePath==filename);
   return File("~/Invoice/" +invoice.ToString(), "application/pdf",Server.UrlEncode(invoice.ToString()));
}
```

The Index View

```
 <table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CreatedInvoice)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.InvoicePath)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreatedInvoice)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InvoicePath)
        </td>
         <td>
 @Html.ActionLink("Download", "GetPdf", new { id = item.InvoicePath })
</td>
</tr>
}
</table>
```

This is my upload file method

```
 public ActionResult fileupload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            if (file != null)
            {

                string ImageN = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);//get the file path
                string physicalPath = Server.MapPath("~/Invoice/" + ImageN);//store the file path in a folder called img

                file.SaveAs(physicalPath);

                Invoice newP = new Invoice();
                newP.InvoicePath = ImageN;
                newP.CreatedInvoice = DateTime.Now;
                db.Invoices.Add(newP);//store the image path in a database
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View();
        }
```

Any suggestions will be Greatly appreciated

Comment: You're using invoice.ToString() to create the path - have you overridden the ToString() method in the Invoice object return the path? Can you see what path is being generated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just Changed the download Method To This

```
 public ActionResult GetPdf(int id)
        {
            var invoice = db.Invoices.Find(id);

            return File("~/Invoice/" + invoice.InvoicePath, "application/pdf", Server.UrlEncode(invoice.InvoicePath));
        }
```

and Changed The Action Link to

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Download", "GetPdf", new { id = item.InvoiceId })
```

dont really know why the above  method did not work

Answer (score 0):

This is what your code should be:

```
public ActionResult GetPdf(string filename)
{
   var invoice = db.Invoices.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.InvoicePath == filename);
   return File("~/Invoice/" + invoice.InvoicePath, "application/pdf", Server.UrlEncode(invoice.InvoicePath));
}
```

I'm not sure why you're Querying the Database though as you're getting the fileName in paramater and that is all you need to serve the file anyways.

You're saving the file name in `InvoicePath` property when file is uploaded, it is this property which you should be using to get the name of file to be downloaded.

Comment: ok so i did try as you posted but i get the error  0x80070002  ,   Requested URL    http://localhost:11809/Invoices/GetPdf/Brief Increment Marking rubric.pdf ,Physical Path    C:\Users\JephyDa1st\Desktop\Ds3Doc\Ds3Project\Supp\Supp\Invoices\GetPdf\Brief Increment Marking rubric.pdf